# Difference between "Activate" & "Publish" options on Android market?

Tags: android

I have uploaded .apk file on my Android market account using my userid & password. I am  yet to publish the app. But I was just curious as to what is the "activate" option on the Android market and how is it different from the "Publish" option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activate is used to flag your apks before you publish them.  If you're using just a single apk, you just need to activate that one apk before you publish it.

If you're using multiple apks, you need to "activate" the apks you want to enable before publishing them.